# FBDSKCoreKit error: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fbsdk, parsefacebookutils

**EDIT**: For more info on this particular bug, follow up with the Facebook Team [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/890351917757088).

I have researched this intensely and have failed to find a solution. Never ran into this issue and now I can't seem to get passed this one.

**Here is the error I am receiving:**

[image: Error I am receiving]

[image: Modules][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `Project: Pods`, `Target: ParseFacebookUtilsV4` and change that value there `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules = YES`

Answer (score 0):

It seams by **Downgrading to Xcode 7.2.1** allows me to compile without any errors. Seems to be an issue with `FBSDKCoreKit` and `Xcode 7.3`.

**Fix:** Downgrade to Xcode 7.2.1, clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I found that allowing non-modular frameworks was not the fix. I had some problems too after upgrading to 7.3, but it's working now. Make sure you are using the latest frameworks...if you are, delete all FBSDK frameworks, re-download the Facebook SDK, and add FBSDK OREKIT, FBSDKLoginKit (if needed), and FBSDKShareKit (if needed) ** Make sure to check the copy items if needed box **. Clean the project and build it. If using CoccoaPods, I would make sure the frameworks are updated to the latest version. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zach You have Parse and Bolts installed with copy if needed checked, correct?

Comment: I have Parse and Bolts installed via CocoaPods, but I don't have a static copy in my project.